# Django fail to reference value after return serializered model object for ajax request

Tags: django

I have a ajax request call QueryDB and try to query the data.

```
def QueryDB(request):

        _exp = request.GET['exp']
        _alg = request.GET['alg']
        _orderby = request.GET['orderby']
        _type = request.GET['type']
        _nOutput = request.GET['nOutput']
        if(_type == 'fp'):
            evs = ev_detection.objects.filter(alg=_alg, exp = _exp)
            order_evs = evs.order_by('score');
        #order_evs = order_evs[0:int(_nOutput)]
        data = serializers.serialize('json', order_evs)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type = "application/json")
```

ev_detection model:

```
 class ev_detection(models.Model):

        imageset = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
        exp = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
        alg = models.CharField(max_length=20)   
        nFrame = models.FloatField()
        xAxis = models.FloatField()
        yAxis = models.FloatField()
        width = models.FloatField()
        height = models.FloatField()
        score = models.FloatField()
        match = models.IntegerField()
```

My AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fpquery').on("click", function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/results/QueryDB',
        data: {
          'exp':'Reasonable',
          'alg':'FT22-OI',
          'type':'fp',
          'orderby': 'score',
          'nOutput': 5     
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data[0].length);
        }
      });
   });
  });
```

The alert popup value "undefined"
But when I change it to `alert(data.length);`it return 5 which is the correct number. I just wonder how can I get the correct json return in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right data already.

`data[0]` is an object. In Javascript, objects don't have a `.length` attribute.

Comment: I can't really reference the data. I output data[0][0] it returns me "undefined".

Comment: Because it's an object, objects have keys not indexes. You should try outputting `data[0]` to see what keys it has: `data[0].fields` would probably work.

Comment: i thought it is already in json format? And does javascript reference object with "."?

Comment: Yes it is. And yes it does (although you can also use strings: `data[0]["fields"]`).

Comment: I really think the data was wrong. Because I tried `data[0]["fields"]` but it return me an object which make sense tho. However in my QueryDB python function I do print data[0] it return me a empty array. What can you recommend to fix my problem?

Comment: hey can you help me up with a similar problem. I really cant solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685535/django-httpresponse-2-query-result-in-json-format